# PostgreSQL v13 WAL sequence number question

Tags: postgresql

I don't understand what are the 40,41,42,43 wal sequence files in my pg_wal directory?

According to [the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-internals.html), segment files are given ever-increasing numbers as names, starting at `000000010000000000000001`.

Why do the `4x` segment files not appear in my backup? Why is there a `3F` after `43`?

```sh
# ls -clt /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/pg_wal/
total 81924
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 jan   29 10.45 00000001000000000000003F
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 jan   29 10.18 000000010000000000000043
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres       59 jan   29 10.18 <font color="#3465A4"><b>archive_status</b></font>
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 jan   29 09.18 000000010000000000000042
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 jan   29 08.18 000000010000000000000041
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 jan   29 07.43 000000010000000000000040
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres      340 jan   27 19.13 000000010000000000000020.00000060.backup
```

My backup server wasn't available between 0:13 and 7:29.

My backup directory:

```sh
# ls -clt /home/pgbackup/wal/
total 524292
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   29 10:13 00000001000000000000003E
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   29 09:13 00000001000000000000003D
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   29 08:13 00000001000000000000003C
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   29 07:29 00000001000000000000003B
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   29 07:29 00000001000000000000003A
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   29 07:29 000000010000000000000039
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   29 00:13 000000010000000000000038
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 23:13 000000010000000000000037
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 22:13 000000010000000000000036
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 21:14 000000010000000000000035
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 20:13 000000010000000000000034
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 19:13 000000010000000000000033
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 18:13 000000010000000000000032
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 17:13 000000010000000000000031
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 16:13 000000010000000000000030
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 15:13 00000001000000000000002F
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 14:30 00000001000000000000002E
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 14:30 00000001000000000000002D
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 14:30 00000001000000000000002C
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 14:30 00000001000000000000002B
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 10:13 00000001000000000000002A
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 09:13 000000010000000000000029
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 08:13 000000010000000000000028
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 07:13 000000010000000000000027
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 06:46 000000010000000000000026
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 06:46 000000010000000000000025
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   28 06:46 000000010000000000000024
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   27 22:13 000000010000000000000023
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   27 21:13 000000010000000000000022
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup 16777216 jan   27 20:13 000000010000000000000021
-rw------- 1 pgbackup pgbackup      340 jan   27 19:13 000000010000000000000020.00000060.backup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The life cycle of WAL segments is:

1. They are created ahead of time, so that there are always some in stock to cope with activity spikes. This process is driven by database activity and `min_wal_size`.
2. At some point, the WAL segment becomes active and is written to.
3. When the segment is full or something else happens that causes a WAL switch, the next segment becomes active.  If archiving is configured, the old WAL segment is archived.
4. Once the segment is archived and no longer needed for anything else (`wal_keep_size`, replication slot), it is removed at the next checkpoint. This can happen in two ways:

   - the old segment is deleted
   - the old segment is renamed and enters the cycle again at step 1

   This is determined by `max_wal_size`, `min_wal_size` and database activity.

In your case, `00000001000000000000003F` is the currently active WAL segment (it has the latest modification timestamp and a low number). `000000010000000000000040` to `000000010000000000000043` are the reserve for the future. `000000010000000000000021` to `00000001000000000000003E` have been completed, archived and removed.

Never look at the timestamp to determine the order of WAL segments, it is all in the name.

This [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-ARCHIVING-WAL):

> The system physically divides this sequence into WAL *segment files*, which are normally 16MB apiece (although the segment size can be altered during initdb). The segment files are given numeric names that reflect their position in the abstract WAL sequence. When not using WAL archiving, the system normally creates just a few segment files and then “recycles” them by renaming no-longer-needed segment files to higher segment numbers. It's assumed that segment files whose contents precede the last checkpoint are no longer of interest and can be recycled.

The parameters are also documented.  Beyond a certain degree of detail, resort to the (well documented open) source and its README files.

Comment: Thank You, that was helpful information. It sould be in the official documentation too...

Comment: It is, see my added comments.